# Implementing `sumproduct` in UNIX shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have some output from a script `thescript` which reads:

```
202 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Now I want to selectively sum this number with `awk`, depending on the value of a `${SUM_MASK}`:

```
SUM_MASK=1,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

I would like to have something like:

```
thescript | awk <SOMETHING>
```

where the each number output of `thescript` gets multiplied by the corresponding number in `${SUM_MASK}`, obtaining:

```
203
```

as result of:
203 = 202 * 1 + 1 * 1 + 0 * 0 + 1 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0 + 0 * 0

This would be similar to the `sumproduct` function in spreadsheet software.

The following code snipets do the trick, but I would like to avoid using process substitution:

```
SUM_MASK="1,1,0,0,0,0,0"; paste <(thescript) <(echo ${SUM_MASK} | tr ',' '\n') | awk '{ SUM += $1 * $2 } END { print SUM }'
```

and named pipes:

```
SUM_MASK="1,1,0,0,0,0,0"; mkfifo fA; mkfifo fB; thescript > fA & echo ${SUM_MASK} | tr ',' '\n' > fB & paste fA fB | awk '{ SUM += $1 * $2 } END { print SUM }' > result.text; rm -f fA fB
```

how could I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you need `awk` for this?

Comment: I presume the number of elements is not always fixed at 7?

Comment: BTW, I'd consider taking both inputs from the command line of your function or script, and unifying the format (to allow either spaces *or* commas for both, for instance). It's a little nonobvious to the reader why your requested calling convention (with one argument taken from a predefined variable and the other from stdin) was chosen.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do not necessarily need `awk`, but I am not sure sure `bash` is used either. I thought `awk` would be less problematic. I could certainly get input from command-line, but the variable is already in place. Either way it is just a slightly different syntax, not much more. The only important thing is that it has to be a one-liner, as the service I am using will not allow me to define a shell script.
@MarkSetchell will that change anything in the implementation you had in mind?

Comment: I have received quite a few very interesting contribution. Given the question, I should probably accept CharlesDuffy or glennjackmann answer's though karafka 's is quite possibly the one that I actually need.

Comment: I ended up using Python because all other option would have required the use of `$` for accessing variables, and I could not find a way of escaping them within the `\immediate\write18{}` LaTeX environment. `python -c "import sys; print(sum(int(l) * w for l, w in zip(sys.stdin, [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])))"`. This is slightly different from what I asked originally but ended up working nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "202 1 0 1 0 0 0" |
awk -v summask="1,1,0,0,0,0,0" '
    BEGIN {split(summask, mask, /,/)}
    {   sumproduct=0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            sumproduct +=  $i * mask[i]
        }
        print sumproduct
    }
'
```

```
203
```

Comment: This is a definitely one of the best answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for external tools such as `awk` here -- bash is capable of resolving this with built-in capabilities only. Consider the below implementation as a function:

```
sumproduct() {
  local -a sum_inputs sum_mask
  local idx result

  # read your sum_inputs into an array from stdin
  IFS=', ' read -r -a sum_inputs # this could be <<<"$1" to use the first argument

  # and your sum_mask from the like-named variable
  IFS=', ' read -r -a sum_mask <<<"$SUM_MASK" # or <<<"$2" for the second argument

  # ...iterate over array elements in sum_inputs; find the corresponding sum_mask; math.
  result=0
  for idx in "${!sum_inputs[@]}"; do
    (( result += ${sum_mask[$idx]} * ${sum_inputs[$idx]} ))
  done
  echo "$result"
}
```

---

To test this:

```
echo "202 1 0 1 0 0 0" | SUM_MASK=1,1,0,0,0,0,0 sumproduct
```

...correctly yields:

```
203
```

Comment: Nice solution.  A possible minor improvement is to de-clutter the update of the `result` variable: `(( result += sum_mask[idx] * sum_inputs[idx] ))`.

Comment: I am not sure this will work with the bash version used by the service, but I will test and report about it. Very nice solution, though!

Comment: @norok2, everything here is compatible with bash 3.2 -- that was released in 2006, so we're talking a full decade. I'm actually pretty sure (but haven't tested) that compatibility extends back into the 2.x series, meaning late-90s.

Comment: (Thus, if it's *not* compatible, your shell is probably `/bin/sh`, not bash at all! However, if you transformed this from a function into a script with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, then it would be guaranteed to be run with bash barring explicit `sh scriptname` type invocation forcing a baseline-POSIX shell; that transformation could be just adding a `#!/bin/bash` at the top and a `sumproduct "$@"` at the bottom).

Answer (score 3):

You do not actually need sum product, but masked summation, for example this should be faster if you have a lot of masked columns.

```
$ awk -v mask='1,1,0,0,0,0,0' 'BEGIN {n=split(mask,m,","); 
                                      for(i=1; i<=n; i++) if(m[i]) ix[i]} 
                                     {sum=0; 
                                      for(i in ix) sum += $i; 
                                      print sum}' file

203
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answer differs from the one @glennjackman posted 2 hours ago.

Comment: first, there is no multiplication.  Second, the size of the main loop is based on nonzero entries only not the full mask size.  Otherwise, there are only so many ways to compute a sum.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Thanks! Here's a plus one.

Comment: Strictly not a sumproduct implementation, but quite possibly the best answer for my use case. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the one-digit multipliers you can make a simple loop

```
SUM_MASK=1,1,0,0,0,0,0
offset=0
sum=0;
for i in 202 1 0 1 0 0 0; do
   j="${SUM_MASK:$offset:1}"
   ((sum += i * j ))
   ((offset+=2))
done
echo "${sum}"
```

This solution can be used in a script `prodsum` that can be called with `thescript | prodsum` :

```
offset=0
sum=0;
for i ; do
   j="${SUM_MASK:$offset:1}"
   ((sum += i * j ))
   ((offset+=2))
done
echo "${sum}"
```

EDIT: When the SUB_MASK can have numbers>9, use the following:

```
SUM_MASK=1,10,0,0,0,0,0
sum=0;
remaining_mask="$SUM_MASK"

for i in 202 1 0 1 0 0 0; do
   j="${remaining_mask%%,*}"
   remaining_mask="${remaining_mask#*,}"
   ((sum += i * j ))
done
echo "${sum}"
```

Comment: Assuming that your multiplicands will only ever be single-digit is... quite an assumption. Have a `10` in the mask and everything's messed up.

Comment: @Charles When I read the OPS question, SUM_MASK can be seen as a set of booleans. I first wanted to rule out the multiplication and just write `(( sum += i ))` after testing `$j -eq 0`. When I want to support values > 10, I should split `$remaining_mask` into a part before and after the first `,`.

Comment: If only single digits were allowed, why have commas at all, vs expressing the mask as `1100000`? Having the commas be in the data implies that they do something useful; better to have a format that reflects actual capabilities than one that looks like it can support multi-digit mask values but breaks if they're ever used.